# PHP get wsdl behind digest authentication

Tags: php, symfony, soap, digest-authentication, http-digest

I have to fetch a SOAP WSDL file that needs a digest authentication.
When I write my \SoapClient($wsdl) I get '403:Access denied' error.

I have acces to the wsdl file via browser, and i tried to save it locally but it's not a best practice giving the wsdl contains a auto-generated parameter that is enivrement related.

How can i do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem some time ago, you could see the solution [here](https://github.com/mblal/CurlSoapClient)
I hope that answers your question

Comment: may you extend your answer, may be provide some code snippets how to use it? as it's not really informational, and this way you may post just a comment, but not an answer.